# Handling duplicate values in Drop down list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my VB.net3.5 application we are showing a state drop downlist
with following values

```
<asp:DropDownList NAME="mailingState" id="mailingState" runat="server">
    <option value="Ak">ALASKA</option>
    <option value="AA">APO AA</option>
    <option value="AE">APO AE</option>
    <option value="AP">APO AP</option>
    <option value="CA">CALIFORNIA</option>
    <option value="AA">DPO AA</option>
    <option value="AE">DPO AE</option>
    <option value="AP">DPO AP</option>
    <option value="FL">FLORIDA</option>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

As you can see there are some duplicate values, which I have to deal with.
When I select any DPO AA(or AE,AP) and there is a server side error and page post backs, state drop down list always shows APO AA(or AE,AP) instead of DPO.
I know its selecting first of the duplicate value.
I tried to select the option by Text also its show APO instead of DPO.
is there any better way to handle duplicates in a drop down list.
When I check, In chrome browser inspect element it shows correct element(DPO AA) selected. But in aspx.vb page on very first line of page_load event when I check for SelectItem is set to APO.
Any ideas how to fix this.

Comment: If you are loading this list from your own dataset, make the value of each option distinct e.g. for APO AA value can be `APO-AA` and for DPO AA value can be `DPO-AA`. Making each option value distinct will fix your issue

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the values, this is some very old code, I have to deal with it.

Comment: How do you populate the data to DropDownList? It is where you need to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're limited to HTTP protocol capabilities.

**GET** request returns `<option selected="selected>` for any of those items. So you can see it as you've generated it

**POST** request to your application gets just whatever$Your$Hierarchy$is$mailingState=AA and there's no way to distinguis between APO/DPO. No matter what text did user selected. So .NET picks first mach for you. SelectedIndex is not transfered by HTTP.

**Solution A** Use some unique values. Like "AA-APO AA" to join current key and value. Or some ID from database.

**Solution B** You'll have to POST the selected index by yourself to you. It means add  and some javascript to your DDL's onchange event to store selectedIndex to that hidden field. And work and re-set the DDL.SelectedIndex afterwards.